# Comparing short references?

Tags: java

Some backstory, I am getting a warning  for some code that I wrote. The warning and the two code excerpts are below. Are they just telling me to use `!.equals()` method instead of `!=` when comparing the two references in the if statement? `minRange` is a short

> Questionable use of reference equality rather than calling equals. Suspicious comparison of short references

```
if (minRange != other.minRange)
     return false;
```

Both these excerpts are unrelated but the warning showed up twice

```
if (mod_system.getMaxRange() != (current_system.getMaxRange()
     changed_data = true;
```

Comment: They're probably short references; it's not 100% clear what you're asking without context, like the signatures/types of the references in question.

Comment: They are short references. I'm moreso asking why is this warning popping up? Does != not work for short references? Sorry if the question isn't clear or can't be answered without context

Comment: `short` is not the same as `Short`, which is why I asked for specifics. For future reference, often simply searching for the error message, or a portion of it, will provide answers.

Comment: Your right, it is Short, not short. My apologies for that.

Comment: (I didn't mean to make a pun with "future reference" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you variable types are `Short`, in which case `==` will only compare references, not values.

So to answer your question, yes you should be using `.equals(Object)`, which unboxes their primitive values for comparison. Otherwise you could do the unboxing yourself with:

```
minRange.shortValue() == other.minRange.shortValue()
```